# Representation of multiple solutions for a variable

Tags: polynomials

Often, we come across answers such as "$x$ can be either $3$ or $5$"

Is there a way to write this down as a single equation?

I have considered $x\in\{3, 5\}$, but this only means that every possible value of $x$ is present in the set. But there may also exist values in the set that $x$ cannot take up. I'm looking for something ​such that every element of the set is a value that $x$ can take up.

Maybe there is a strict version of $\in$ for this?

Comment: You could say $x=4\pm1$, but as far as I’m aware saying $x\in\{3,5\}$ is completely accurate. Use MathJax to format future questions on this site

Comment: I think $x\in\{3,5\}$ is correct and preferable to $x=4\pm1$ which, in some contexts, would mean $3\leq x\leq5$.

Comment: It does not make sense to say that $x$ can take every value in the set... In each instantiation $x$ will only have one value.

Comment: @PierreCarre Thanks, I've edited my question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your solution process is clearly a sequence of reversible steps ("if and only if"s) that ends with "$x\in\{3,5\}$", then you can expect readers to understand that this means both values are solutions, since you've shown that the original equation is *equivalent* to it.

If your logical argument is more complicated, then the natural-language part of what you write is important. You could say "$x=3$ and $x=5$ are solutions to the given equation" or "the given equation is equivalent to $x\in\{3,5\}$".